# AQGridView demo application can not work in xcode 4 and ios 4.3

Tags: ios4, xcode4, aqgridview

I'm trying to develop an `AQGridView` in iPhone. I downloaded the .zip file of `AQGridView` from GitHub social coding site. The example application of `AQGridView` (ImageDemo, SpringBoard, ExpanderDemo) can't be run in Xcode 4 and iOS SDK 4.3.

At compile time the error is showing:

```
"AlanQuatermain-AQGridView-4072978/Examples/ImageDemo/main.m:14:5: error:
unexpected '@' in program [3]"
```

The error indicator is shown at `main()`. The code of `main()` is bellow:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    int retVal;
    @autoreleasepool {
        retVal = UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, nil);
    }

    return retVal;
}
```

My questions are:

1. How can I overcome the error?
2. What `@autoreleasepool{.....}` is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@autoreleasepool was introduced in LLVM 3.0,the compiler available in Xcode 4.2. Since you’re using Xcode 3.2.6, you have LLVM 1.6 and GCC, neither of which recognises that directive.

You can change the code to use NSAutoreleasePool instead of @autoreleasepool so that it builds with Xcode 3.2.6. For example, replace:

@autoreleasepool {
    …
}
with:

NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [NSAutoreleasePool new];
…
[pool drain];